# how to SAML authentication enable in azure web app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, saml, saml-2.0

Is SAML authentication possible in Azure Web Apps? If possible, how can I configure Azure AD for SAML authentication? I tried finding a solution but the only Microsoft documents I've found regarding this is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/saml-toolkit-tutorial . The problem within the document is that it doesn't specify any code related information

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you need two things.

The application needs a [client-side stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

Azure AD has to be configured as an [Enterprise application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-non-gallery-applications).